# TypeScript complaining that array.map is not present on array of type string[]

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

I have an Angular 2 project with TypeScript. I don't understand why TypeScript live compiler is complaining about the `info.map`?

> Error message: unresolved function or method map()

When I run it in the browser, ***is working just fine***, but I don't understand why it happens and more importantly how TypeScript determines in which if /else branch I'm in.

The code:

```
let addInfo = (info: string|string[]) =>  {
        if(_.isString(info)){

            console.log('info is a string');
            infos.push(info);

        }else if(_.isArray(info)){

            console.log('info is an array');
            info.map( x => { infos.push(x) }); // here is the compiling error- map is red.
        }
 }
```

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Typescript compiler doesn't recognise lodash's function call as a type check. You can try "if(info instanceof String)" and in the else branch typescript can assume info is array.

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/lodash.d.ts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript compiler doesn't recognise lodash's function call as a type check. You can try "if(info instanceof String)" and in the "else" branch typescript can assume the "info" is array.

This works for me in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html):

```
let addInfo = (info: string|string[]) =>  {
    if(info instanceof String){
        info;
    } else {
        info.map(s => s);
    }
 }
```

#### Update

Thanks to @Tamas Hegedus, shared knoweledge about custom type-guards. I haven't heard about them before. I've decided to put here quotation from [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) about User-Defined Type Guards:

> It just so happens that TypeScript has something called a type guard.
>   A type guard is some expression that performs a runtime check that
>   guarantees the type in some scope. To define a type guard, we simply
>   need to define a function whose return type is a type predicate:
>
> ```
> function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
>     return (<Fish>pet).swim !== undefined;
> }
> ```
>
> **pet is Fish** is our type predicate in this example. A predicate takes
>   the form **parameterName is Type**, where **parameterName** must be the name
>   of a parameter from the current function signature.

Comment: Yes, that is a good explanation. Thanks @TSV :) But do you know if it's possible to make Typescript recognize the lodash functions? - they are so nice compared to the instanceof / or other native JavaScript checks.. Webstorm is underlining in red all project files that have this types errors and i have multiple files in red because of this. I don't know which are the real errors and which are not. Is annoying..

Comment: I do understand your point. I'm not sure typescript understands another type checknig except it's own... Are you using "lodash.d.ts"? If so, probably I'm right...

Comment: @Alon Typescript has user-defined type guards, and lodash.d.ts takes advantage of them. Just use it and the compiler will not complain anymore.

Comment: You should really use `typeof info === 'string'` -- `instanceof` is going to give you false positives on wrapped `String` objects which won't behave the way you expect. It's also likely to be faster to use `typeof`

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution:

I had the `@types/lodash/index.d.ts` file, but i believe was an older version.
As soon as I installed the new version - everything worked as expected.

So for people with Angular2 CLI project, just run:
`npm install @types/lodash` :)

Comment: I didn't know about user-defined type-guards. Thank you, guys!