# Angular 2 CLI project - Error: Duplicate identifier Promise - how to solve this?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, angular2-cli

I have an angular2 CLI project.

Two days ago, because my Webstorm IDE complained about new Promise and string[].map could not been resolved, i forcefully installed `es6-promise` inside `node_modules/@types` folder using:

```
npm install @types/es6-promise --save
```

You can find the related question here: [TypeScript complaining that array.map is not present on array of type string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793756/typescript-complaining-that-array-map-is-not-present-on-array-of-type-string)

Webstorm IDE finally worked as expected, no red underlined files , but today when I reloaded the app in the browser, I got this 6 errors:

[image]

I would say that the message error is pretty straight forward. The **newly installed types** in `index.d.ts` file from `@types` folder, **are colliding with the ones form** `node_module/typescript` - the main module of typescript compiler - which Angular2 CLI created and is using by default.

*Essentially: declarations like: "`declare class Promise<T> etc..`" inside `@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts` **are the same** with the ones in `typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts`.*

**Ouestion:** ***how to get around this? What code is needed to eliminate this conflict?***

As of now (2 October 2016) - if you do a fresh `ng init` - in Webstorm IDE - you can't have `let myPromise = new Promise()` or any other `es6 operators` - without the file being marked with an error.
If you install stuff in @types on your own - you get ***this duplicate identifier error..***

Not being presumptuous here, but I'm pretty sure it's not only me - just created a fresh ng2CLI project. Can't get around this. Can anyone confirm that this is happening on their end? I lost half a day trying to solve this nonsense. Any thoughts on this matter are highly appreciated:) Thanks.

Comment: Check your TS config. if you have `es6` in `lib` section (and you probably should), you don't need `@types/es6-promise` or any other ES6 types.

Comment: yep i know, "lib": ["es6","dom"], and is not working. I just find out that i can't use Promises in my angular 2 project. Crazy!

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but this is a problem of Webstorm in the first place, and adding @types/es6-promise is a mistake here (btw, the link for related question above isn't related at all). I would suggest to step back, remove @types/es6-promise  and re-ask the question according to Webstorm output. A reproducible repo that includes A2 project and .idea folder would help.

Comment: @estus, yes man you are right! turns out that was a webstorm problem also - you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-2-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator

Comment: Thanks, nice to know that CLI doesn't play well with Jetbrains products (used non-CLI projects with no problems).

Comment: I'm using the CLI fine with Webstorm, no problems at all.